# How to stop a 'hive on spark' job after execute a hivesql in hue query

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hue, cloudera-manager

I'm using Cloudera Manager 6.1.1 and HUE. My hive engine is spark. When I execute a hivesql in hue query, there always will start a hive on spark job, and it won't stop.

[image]

Comment: I hive to kill this job everytime.

Comment: Can you add the exact commands that you are using to list the job?  And then the commands you are using to stop/kill the job?

Comment: just work in hueUI, execute hive sql

Answer (score 0):

I find this.Hive will fix in version 4.0.0.
[https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-14162][1]